# reset autoincrement when using a data adapter in c#

Tags: c#, datatable, auto-increment, tableadapter

I'm trying to take an existing Access database file (template.mdb) as a template for a new file.
I want to drop some tables' rows (but keep other tables).
I "access" the table via TableAdapters generated by Visual Studio 2010 (via add item -> data -> DataSet).

While trying to drop some of the existing tables' contents and reset the auto increment counter I cannot accomplish the second task.
I'm trying do this by

```
var adapter = new MyTableTableAdapter();
var targetTable = adapter.GetData();
// mark each row for deletion
foreach (DataRow row in targetTable.Rows)
  row.Delete();
```

// found the following sequence [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972699/reset-autoincrement-in-datatable).

```
targetTable.IDProductColumn.AutoIncrement = true;
targetTable.IDProductColumn.AutoIncrementSeed = 0;
targetTable.IDProductColumn.AutoIncrementStep = -1;
targetTable.IDProductColumn.AutoIncrementSeed = -1;

// apply the changes
adapter.Update(targetTable);
```

This indeed deletes the existing rows but doesn't reset the auto increment.

How can this be accomplished?

---

edit: complete workflow right now

1. Copy the temple mdb file
2. establish connection to copied file
3. try to delete all rows of some tables, but not all
4. read new data from an external xml file, containing references like this:

   `<tableARow><id>1</id></tableARow>` // if this row get's an id <> 1 ...

   `<tableBRow><idRefTableARow>1</idRefTableARow></tableBRow>` // ... this row will not import correctly
5. add this data to the "new" data base

Comment: you want to maintain some of the data in the table or you want to flush all of the data and start with a new auto increment?

Comment: I only want to drop some tables and reset their auto-increment value.
The reason is that if I import new data the id's contained in them mismatch.

`<someTableRow><id>1</id></someTableRow> <someOtherTableRow><idRef>1<idRef></someOtherTableRow>`

If the data set for `someTableRow` is imported with id 10 (since this is the current value of auto increment) I get a key error if I try to import `someOtherTableRow`

Answer (score 0):

You could just build a new Data Table in code and add the columns required rather than loading an old Table and removing all items.

```
var Table = new DataTable();


var columnA = new DataColumn();
columnA.ColumnName = "Your Column Name";
var columnB = new DataColumn();
columnB.ColumnName = "Your Column Name";
var columnC = new DataColumn();
columnC.ColumnName = "Your Column Name";



Table.Columns.Add(columnA);
Table.Columns.Add(columnB);
Table.Columns.Add(columnC);
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I tried to drop the table and recreate it but this gives me an exception:
Cannot delete table. It's either the actual index or used in a relation (translated, may not be the original English text).

Comment: Build Your tables in Memory, are you saving the data Back to the Database?

Comment: The sequence right now is:


1) Copy the temple mdb file

2) establish connection to copied file

3) try to delete all rows of some selected tables

4) read new data from an external xml source

5) add this data to the "new" data base

Answer (score 0):

If you want to flush all the data and reuse the table then

```
dt.Clear();
dt.Column["IDProductColumn"].AutoIncrementStep = -1;  --Change the step value to get around the logic in the set_AutoIncrementSeed
dt.Column["IDProductColumn"].AutoIncrementSeed = -1;  --reset the AutoIncrementSeed

dt.Column["IDProductColumn"].AutoIncrementStep = 1;  -- set the new step
dt.Column["IDProductColumn"].AutoIncrementSeed = 1;  --  set the new seed
```

Comment: look like code I tried except the `targetTable.Clear()` part.
But if I add the `targetTable.Clear()` it doesn't even remove the existing rows, since there are now rows marked as "to delete" in the update step.