# DataTable Decrement column value after delete row

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, datatable

Hi. I have a `DataTable` one of the column is set to `AutoIncrement` is true. Basically I am adding some text box values to the DataTable and then binding it to the Grid View. What I am trying to achieve is if I delete a row from the grid view the row in the DataTable is also need to be deleted and also decrement the primary key column.

DataTable is declared like this `private DataTable table = new DataTable();` and code is:

```
DataColumn promoDetailsID = new DataColumn();
promoDetailsID.ColumnName = "promoDetailsID";
promoDetailsID.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
promoDetailsID.AutoIncrement = true;
promoDetailsID.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
promoDetailsID.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
table.Columns.Add(promoDetailsID);
table.Columns.Add("StartRange", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("EndRange", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("AllocationCases", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("AllocationUnits", typeof(string));
if (ViewState["dtTable"] != null)
{
    table = (DataTable)ViewState["dtTable"];
}
table.Rows.Add(null,TxtStartRange.Text.Trim(), TxtEndRange.Text.Trim(), TxtAllocationAmount.Text.Trim(), TxtAllocationCases.Text.Trim(), TxtAllocationUnits.Text.Trim());
grdPromotions.DataSource = table;
grdPromotions.DataBind();
ViewState["dtTable"] = table;
```

This is the code when I am trying to delete row from grid.

```
 protected void grdPromotions_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

        if (ViewState["dtTable"] != null)
        {
            table = (DataTable)ViewState["dtTable"];
            int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
            table.Rows[e.RowIndex].Delete();
        }
        table.AcceptChanges();
        grdPromotions.DataSource = table;
        grdPromotions.DataBind();
        ViewState["dtTable"] = table;

    }
```

There is no error I am getting but the DataTable is not updating after delete.

Comment: Don't store a `DataTable` in ViewState, if you need to persist it between postbacks use the `Session` instead.

Comment: visit this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972699/reset-autoincrement-in-datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't use a real database it makes no sense to use `DataRow.Delete` which just sets it's `RowState` to `Deleted`. What you want to do is to remove the row from the `DataTable`.

```
table.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
```

If you also want to decrement the primary key column, you have to make the column writable:

```
table.Columns[0].ReadOnly = false;
```

Then you need to update the value manually:

```
int counter = 0;
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    row[0] = ++counter;
}
table.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
```

Side-note: don't store a `DataTable` in `ViewState`, if you need to persist it between postbacks use the `Session` instead. Session lives in memory whereas `ViewState` will be serialized and stored in the rendered html, so it will also be transferred to the client.